# Parse Japanese currency String with java.text.NumberFormat

Tags: java, unicode, cjk, number-formatting

I face problems parsing a Japanese currency string in Java. It seems that the Yen symbol is not matching what java think it should be. Here is my code:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
String s = "¥200";
Number n = f.parse(s);
```

This will throw an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "¥200"
at java.text.NumberFormat.parse(NumberFormat.java:333)
```

Seems that java uses a different symbol for Yen ("\uFFE5")

Can someone help with that?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try change the character "¥"(0xC2A5) to "￥"(0xEFBFA5).
"¥"(0xC2A5) is special character in Japanese locale.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and 0xEFBFA5 ( char 65509 ) is the right one to use. But in Java it does not produce the ￥ sign. but a a square. Also check it out here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffe5/index.htm

Answer (score 5):

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.UK);
        String s = "£200";
        Number n = f.parse(s);
```

AND

```
    NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
    String s = "$200";
    Number n = f.parse(s);
```

Will have the same affect.  NumberFormat works on numbers, not on a string character i.e. you need to remove the currency symbol if you are allowing NumberFormat to parse integers only (the default).  What you can do is this:

```
NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPAN);
String s = "¥200";
f.setParseIntegerOnly(false);
Number n = f.parse(s);
```

This will allow the Yen character through.  Try it with $ and it fails.  But change the local to US and the $ is allowed and the Yen is not.

Comment: Hi palentjones, I think you have a mistake. $ and £ clearly work with my code if you set the locale correctly ( so your examples work just fine... ). Please note i am getting a currency instance for the NumberFormat.

Comment: Hmm.  I agree I don't know what's happening here.  I think it seems to be working on JPY for Japan e.g. this works:
 NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.JAPANESE);
  f.setCurrency(Currency.getInstance("JPY"));
  String s = "JPY 200";
  Number n = f.parse(s);